# how to remove the blur property in child element?

Tags: javascript, css, sass

there is issue in code.

```
<div class="total">
 <div class="part">
   <h2>fff</h2>
</div>
</div>
<style>
.total{
filter:blur(5px);
}
.part{
filter:none;
}
</style>
```

in part class I added filter:none,it still have parent filter property.please help.

Comment: i have still saw the  solved things.But  on the problems,i can't solve problem.not indepepdent div!!!!  it have parent div.

Comment: https://smartslider3.com/video-slider/#three

Comment: sometimes you need to understand that some problem are impossible to solve in the way they are presented [like described in the duplicate question] Thus you need to look for other ways to achieve what you want

Comment: `When using the blur or opacity property, it is not possible to ignore the child element. If you apply either of those properties to parent element, it will automatically apply to child elements too.`

Comment: Dear Afif! very thanks.Now If I solve this problem,how will I do?

Comment: simply read the duplicate question, you will find all what you need there